# JS + math: calculate permutation or combination of substrings

Tags: javascript, math

I'm not sure if "combination" is the right word, but i'd like to scan a string in order to obtain all the possible substring like
ex.

```
var str = "abcd";

// do something here, a for loop i guess...

WANTED OUTPUT:
a
ab
abc
abcd
b
bc
bcd
c
cd
d
```

I'm not interested in results like dcba, therefore i'm not looking for permutations...
what's the function to do that?

thanks!!

Comment: Have you given it a go?

Comment: Are you sure you do not want 'ac','ad','abd','acd', 'bd'?

Comment: @kennebec: He asks for substrings, not for subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy you can do it by yourself too :

```
var str = "abcd";
var substrings = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){ 
     for (var j = i + 1; j <= str.length; j++)
     substrings.push(str.substring(i, j));
}
```

Comment: sorry i havn't sought the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get all possible substrings (you're right, it's not "permutations"), you can just use two nested loops for start and end indices:

```
var str = "abcd";
var substrings = [],
    len = str.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    for (var j=i+1; j<=len; j++)
        substrings.push(str.slice(i, j));

substrings;
// ["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c", "cd", "d"]
```

If you want to get the empty substring, just add that to the initialisation of `substrings`.

Comment: mine and your answer is totally same what a coincidence :)

Comment: @kennebec: Which combination do you miss? The `substrings` array contains exactly the output which the OP wanted.